# Free Downvotes!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, down-votes

A bug I've just noticed over the past two days... downvotes aren't costing me anything!

I downvoted something a day ago and noticed that my rep stayed constant (not supposed to happen), but the recipient lost 2 points (as should happen).  I thought this might be a one-off bug or might be corrected at midnight, but that apparently isn't the case.  I didn't lose a point overnight.  Today, I saw another post I wanted to downvote, and noted my reputation (in case the same thing happened again).  I downvoted, and again, no loss of 1 point.  (The recipient, again, lost 2 points.)

EDIT:
It should be noted that both of these downvotes were on questions, not answers.  I just tried (and undid) an answer downvote, and the rep behaved as expected.

I've only downvoted 4 times in my whole SE career, so I may be missing something, but this doesn't seem right...

Comment: Any difference between downvoting answers and questions?

Comment: @Thomas Good thought!  I just downvoted/unvoted an answer, and found that the rep behaved as expected (I lost a point, they lost 2 points).  It appears my bug is only relevant on questions.

Comment: From what I understand, you actually don't loose points from downvoting a question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.... (boy do I feel dumb now...)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The information page for the [downvoting privilege](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-down) states:

> - Downvotes on *answers* remove **1** reputation from you, the voter.
> - Downvotes on *questions* are **free**. ([Why?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))